# loading dynamically discovered images in the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

The mySql database contains the images that my page needs.   They are not known at script load time.
When I discover the image names, I am sucessfully preloading the needed small thumbnails, but the bigger image that is needed later paints like a snail.   I need to figure out how to start the downlaod of the big images while the page is rendering the small ones.   This should by an async operation as I do not want to block my page.  Can someone suggest how to get the big images loaded before they are needed?

Comment: just how many "big" images are we talking abouT? and how "big"? Preloading one hundred 50meg images is going to be slow no matter what you do. 0.5gigs is going to be a huge hit on most anyone's network pipe.

Comment: At this time I am trying to load 12 "big images" totaling under 15 meg.  If I ever get this to work, I may have more so I would appreciate any words of wisdom about very large sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

**1.** Load your page naturally, with the thumbnails.

**2.** When your page is loaded, use javascript to add the images to the page, but in an invisible manner.

### Example code

```
<html>
    <!-- head, start of body, your normal code, etc -->

    <?php
        /* when you gather your images, place the URLs
        of the big images in an array called $bigImages
        for example. Then, add quotes around them (we
        are going to create a single String) */

        for($i=0; $i<count($bigImages); $i++)
            $bigImages[$i] = '"'.$bigImages[$i].'"';

        // $myList will become a String: "url1","url2", etc
        $myList = implode(',',$bigImages);
    ?>

    <script>
        // put all url's in a js variable
        var bigImages = [<?php echo $myList; ?>];

        // when the normal page is loaded
        window.onload = function(){
            // create some code to append to the body
            var preloader = '<div id="preloader">';
            for(var i=0; i<bigImages.length; i++)
                preloader += '<img src="'+bigImages[i]+'" alt="">';
            preloader += '</div>';

            // insert your images in the page
            document.body.innerHTML += preloader;
        };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code inserts the `<img>` tags in the page once it is loaded. But now you need to hide them, with css:

```
#preloader{
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    left:-9999px;
}
```

**Don't** use `display:none;`, because that will prevent them from loading.

### Edit

Ann, you seem to run into some problems, so I tried this code and came up with an example page that you can just copy and paste in a new php file to test it out, and see if it works. This should open a page with 3 large images in it, loaded with javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the normal page, without the big images</p>
    <?php
        $bigImages=["http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg","http://blog.gettyimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Siberian-Tiger-Running-Through-Snow-Tom-Brakefield-Getty-Images-200353826-001.jpg","http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/52cddfb169beddee2a6c2246/the-29-coolest-us-air-force-images-of-the-year.jpg"];
        for($i=0; $i<count($bigImages); $i++)
            $bigImages[$i] = '"'.$bigImages[$i].'"';
        $myList = implode(',',$bigImages);
    ?>
    <script>
        var bigImages = [<?php echo $myList; ?>];
        window.onload = function(){
            alert('Now that the normal page is fully loaded, we are going to add the images with javascript.');
            var preloader = '<div id="preloader">';
            for(var i=0; i<bigImages.length; i++)
                preloader += '<img src="'+bigImages[i]+'" alt="">';
            preloader += '</div>';
            document.body.innerHTML += preloader;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As for the sizes of the images, I agree with the comments on your question, 1MB is already a lot for an image on the web, so it all comes down to the purpose of your site. If people are going to download these images and need really high quality, it could be necessary to keep them that way (even though they would just need the high quality once they download them) but if the purpose is just to display them on your page, consider lowering their size to a maximum of 300kB, which should be enough for today's average monitor.

Adobe Photoshop has an option for controlling their size under *File* / *Save for Web and devices* where you can adjust the compression of the images (they most certainly won't lose that much quality if you lower them from 100% to 70%)

Comment: I have spent several hours trying to implement you elegant solution.  I am stopped on the line
 var bigImages = [<?php echo $myList; ?>];  For some reason, the netbeans ide keeps giving me the following error.
  Expected an operand but found <
       var bigImages = [<?php echo $myList; ?>];
I think this line is legal and so must be missing something.

Comment: @AnnMaybury: hi, I just tried this code and the only error I noticed was that I wrote `window.load` instead of `window.onload` (I changed that in my answer. The line you are talking about works for me and should output to something like `var bigImages = ["url1","url2","url3"];` when executed. Also, see my edit at the bottom of my post.

Comment: is your file a .php or a .html.  It seems to make a difference here.

Comment: Of course, it is php, since you get your image list from your database. You need to execute it on a server, or on your local server. See how the php variable $bigImages contains a list of the URL's? That is where you should add them during your SQL query for this script to work.